# Changing actionbar color not working

Tags: colors, android-actionbar, themes

I'm trying to change my action bar color to royal blue but it stays black despite everything I try. I've set the color code in my color.xml file and the theme is set to AppTheme in AndroidManifest.xml. I don't know what else could cause it to not work. Here is my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/royal_blue</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use "colorPrimary" for configuring action bar color. You can  use following files for styles configuration.You are recomended to use Toolbar to act as ActionBar

values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>  
</style>
   <!-- Application theme to be used -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
</resources>
```

values-v22/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>   
</style>
</resources>
```

Please note to create another folder in in res folder named values-v22.This will be used by Lollipop devices.And values/styles.xml will be used  by pre-lollipop devices.